# Linq C# com ordem

Tags: c#, linq

Tenho uma consulta LINQ que lista os aniversariantes do mes corrente:

```
        Ramal[] RamalAniver = (from a in db.Ramais
                               where a.sAniversario.Contains(DiaAniversario + "/" + MesAniversario) && a.bAtivo == true
                               select a)
                               .Union(
                               from c in db.Ramais
                               where c.sAniversario.Contains("/" + MesAniversario) && c.bAtivo == true
                               orderby c.sAniversario
                               select c
                               ).ToArray();
```

Porém quando montei ela, a intençao era na primeira consulta trazer o aniversariante do dia como primeiro registro, e na segunda os aniversariantes do mes corrente. A consulta esta retornando os registros mas o aniversariante do dia não fica em primeiro...

Quando a lista é montada a ordem não é mantida... como fazer para ele manter a ordem que coloquei no Union?

Comment: É só pôr a ordem fora do `Union`

Answer (score 0):

O Linq não garante a manutenção da ordem, então você pode usar um truque.

```
Ramal[] RamalAniver =
    (from a in db.Ramais
    where a.sAniversario.Contains(DiaAniversario + "/" + MesAniversario) && a.bAtivo == true
    select new { Ramal = a, Ordem = 0 })
    .Union(
    from c in db.Ramais
    where c.sAniversario.Contains("/" + MesAniversario) && c.bAtivo == true
    orderby c.sAniversario
    select new { Ramal = c, Ordem = 1 })
    .OrderBy(n => n.Ordem)
    .Select(n => n.Ramal)
    .ToArray();
```

Tudo bem que está adicionando um pouco mais de complexidade, mas assim você se mantém dentro do contexto do Linq, com seus benefícios.

Basicamente você estaria criando um novo tipo com 2 propriedade, uma é o `Ramal` e a outra é um `int` com a ordem imposta pelo teu modelo, e, após usá-lo para ordenar o resultado, jogando esse auxiliar fora para retornar apenas os dados que você quer.

Acredito que isto resolva o seu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Pesquisei e juntando o resultado consegui a solução:

Simplifiquei a query trazendo somente o aniversariante do mês:

Ramal[] RamalAniver = (from c in db.Ramais
                                   where c.sAniversario.Contains("/" + MesAniversario) && c.bAtivo == true
                                   orderby c.sAniversario
                                   select c
                                   ).ToArray();

e usando esta expressão consegui deixa o aniversariante do dia em primeira posição e depois em ordem por dia do mês:

RamalAniver = RamalAniver.OrderByDescending(x => x.sAniversario == DiaAniversario 
                + "/" + MesAniversario).ThenBy(x => x.sAniversario).ToArray();

Se alguem puder detalhar o entendimento desta expressão, agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

Considerando que você pode converter as datas de aniversário em DateTime temos a seguinte solução:

```cs
var dataHoje = DateTime.Now;
var aniversariantesDoMes =  pessoas.Where(p => p.DataNascimento.Month == dataHoje.Month && p.DataNascimento.Day >= dataHoje.Day )
        .OrderBy(d => new DateTime(dataHoje.Year,d.DataNascimento.Month,d.DataNascimento.Day));
```